# Error passing ArrayList from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have an important question but firs sorry for my english, I only know the basic. Well my problem is that I have an error passing an ArrayList from a servlet to jsp page:

```
<% ArrayList<Usuario> u= (ArrayList<Usuario>)session.getAttribute("listado");%>
<table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tr bgcolor="blue">
        <td>Usuario</td><td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Apellido</td><td>Clave</td> 
    </tr>
<% for(int i=0;i<u.size();i++){ %>
<% Usuario usuario = u.get(i); %>
<tr>
<td> <%= usuario.getUsuario() %></td>
<td> <%= usuario.getNombre() %></td>
<td> <%= usuario.getApellido() %></td>
<td> <%= usuario.getClave() %></td>
</tr>
<%} %>


</table>
```

That's how I'm doing this but I receive an error in:

```
<% for(int i=0;i<u.size();i++){ %>
```

What I'm doing wrong? also my servlet Method is like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher rd;

    try {
        Connection cn = MySQLConnection.obtenerConexion();
        String sql = "select * from tb_usuario";
        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<Usuario> listado = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        while (rs.next()){
            Usuario usu = new Usuario(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4));
            listado.add(usu);
        }
        request.setAttribute("listado", listado);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/listado.jsp");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope you could help me!

Answer (score 3):

You should not use scriptlets in your JSP. You should use EL and tags in your JSP.

e.g.

```
${listado}
```

Comment: I know how to use it but I need to do it with scriptlets yuck

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the variable in `request` object while retrieving from `session`, which is not present hence the issue.

You are setting the attribute in `doPost` as below":

```
 request.setAttribute("listado", listado);
```

You are retrieving the attribute in your JSP as below":

```
 <% ArrayList<Usuario> u= (ArrayList<Usuario>)session.getAttribute("listado");%>
```

Please use the same scope `session` or `request` in both places.

Comment: Yes, sorry I posted another code, now it's fixed with request but I'm receiving the same error.

Comment: @JosueP.Corzo: How did you fix? Are you using `session` now? Can you please print the `u` and `u.size()` after this line `<% ArrayList<Usuario> u= (ArrayList<Usuario>)session.getAttribute("listado");%>` and see what are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

`scriptlets`are discouraged to use in ajsp page, use `JSTL tags` instead. use `c-foreach tag` to iterate over your arrayList in your jsp page. and you are setting an attribute in a request scope and trying to get it in session scope in your jsp.

[heres the link](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/jsp/jstl-forEach.jspx)  which explains c-foreach tag

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the value in to request scope

```
  request.setAttribute("listado", listado);
```

but then trying to access it in session scope.

```
 session.getAttribute("listado");
```

due to this u might get a null pointer exception in

```
 u.size()...
```

try to access it in request scope

```
 request.getAttribute("xxxxxx")
```

try to avoid adding java code inside JSP whihc is a bad practice. use EL and JSTL instead. you can to the casting part inside the code too..